# Looking for old space fantasy series

Tags: story-identification, space, teleportation

All I can remember from this series is a latino being elected president at the start and a rat who can teleport.

its a book series with multiple books

i read it as a child checked out from an old public library, would have been in the 90s

Comment: That's not a lot to go on with. You have to add more details, otherwise this question will end up being closed. You may find this [thread](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) helpful.

Comment: TV series?  Book series?  When and where did you see/read it?

Answer (score 7):

Could it be [**The Stainless Steel Rat for President**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stainless_Steel_Rat) by Harry Harrison?

It's a comic science fiction novel written in 1982.

There are no teleporting rats, but the main character is known as "The Rat" and is a thief known for sneaking and breaking into secure buildings.  His real name is **James Bolivar diGriz**. (thanks to Paulie D for reminding me to put that in)

This book is part of a series, and the plot of this one is about deposing a dictator in Latin America.

Comment: ...and his name is **James Bolivar diGriz**

Comment: @Paulie_D oops, let me add that.

Comment: i dont think this is the one, the rat character has the power of teleportation i remember that specifically

Comment: @PeterHPottinger apologies for that, it was just the best I could do with vague information.